Extremely Imbalanced and Gapped Dataset in Regression Problem
Currently I am working with a biological dataset with a range of 0-to-1 to do a multi-task regression with Deep Learning. However, this dataset has an empty gap in the range 0 to 0.2 (however there are several datapoints which are 0s) which can't be interpolated due to biological reason. In addition, there is also high tendency of a skewed data around 0.3.
Until now I have only tried to train my model with standard HuberLoss and MSELoss and tried several type of models. However, I still don't get "good" prediction result with pearson correlation of only (~0.65). I came across an article about weighted MSE but most of them talking about classification problem rather than regression. In addition, I read an article about imbalanced dataset in regression but seems like they did interpolation for the data.
My question: is there other method to improve my model further? If so how could I approach it?
Many thanks in advance!
Edit: I had tried simple weighting for my data based on binning of the values' frequency but it didn't help much.

I don't know which correlation you refer to, but using this to quantify your model's performance is most likely a bad method.

Thanks for your response. I am using pearson correlation, and my expectation is that my predicted value will be linearly related into the true value.
I know that there are other metrics like MAE, MSE(used for loss_fn), etc. but since the value range from 0-to-1 it will "look-like" small. Hence, I decided to use perason correlation with a graph for checking my result.

Folks will be better able to offer advice if they better understand the Business Domain. You were rather vague about what X and y represent, and whether 0.1 corresponds to “infeasibly high energy” or “toxic” or something else. The more we understand about your experimental situation, the more likely we can help.

Really thanks for the advice @J_H. Adding the context, I am dealing with "RNA modification" where the modification occurs "co-transcriptionally". My hypothesis is that "RNA sequence only" is enough to say that "hey (protein X)" you need to modify this site as much as y%.
Back to my data, 0 means no modification, 1 shows that the site is fully modified. However, to prevent false-positive from the pipeline, any site with <0.1 will be treated as 0s.
